# Two "While Do" Conditional Inside of a Main Function

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I want to ask about my code below, that doesn't run as I expected when I use for loop, that show the result of all five data in total is 26, since I want to know what happens here.

```
function main() {
    var levels = parseInt(5,10);
    var points = new Array();
    
    var count = 0;
    while(count<levels){
        var elem = [4,5,6,7,4]; // in total must be 26
        points[count] = elem[count];
        count++;
    }
    
    var sum = 0;
    while(count<levels){
        var sum = sum + points[count];
        count++;
    } // I can make it worked using for loop

    console.log(sum)
} 

main()
```

Comment: You would need to reset `count` to 0 before the second while.  Because you already made `count` greater than or equal to `levels` during the first while loop.

Comment: oh I see, I try to reset count with "var",  

var sum = 0, count = 0;
So the first while loop affecting variables outside of the scope. Thanks for your explanation

Comment: `parseInt(5,10)` really?

Comment: Sorry, I get it from the demonstration using "readline()" that input string (I think). So I need to convert it with parseInt. So what do you think? Maybe my understanding needs some correction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var sum = 0;
count = 0; // Reset count to 0
while(count<levels){
```

Will return 26